# How can I visualize permissions to my users on our intranet?

Tags: permissions, access

There have been quite a few people in my organization who have expressed confusion about who has access to what.
This is also making them reluctant to use SharePoint. Because this isn't clear to them.
Preferably, they would like a nice picture, maybe on every page, showing who has access and what their rights are.

Has this been done before? Is there a way to import the permissions of a site/list into a nice Visio diagram or something of the sort? And have it visible to all?

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like http://permissionsmanager.codeplex.com/

Comment: this is a permissions management tool, i need something that displays who has access to what on the site where the user has navigated to.

Answer (score 0):

Trying the demo version right now, but this looks like what your asking about: http://www.docusnap.com/en/docusnap/permission-analysis